# IllegalArgumentException while picking image from gallery on Sony z2

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

When I run script on Sony Z2 it throws this Exception, although it runs smoothly in Samsung s4:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: filename cannot be
>   null
>
> at (MyDetailsPage.java:274)

And here is my program and java:274 is in outside code:

```
 public  Bitmap decodeScaledDownBitmapFromDatabase(String imagePath,int requiredHeight,int requiredWidth){
       final BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        Matrix matrix;

        options.inSampleSize=calculateInputImageSize(options, requiredHeight, requiredWidth);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
        bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        int angel=0;


                    try{

java : 276         ExifInterface exifInterface=new ExifInterface(imagePath);

                   int orientation=exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

                   if (orientation==ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90){
                   angel=90;
                   }
                   else if(orientation==ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180){
                angel=180;
            }
            else if (orientation==ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270){
                angel=270;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image could not be selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        matrix=new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angel);
        Bitmap readyBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);

        return readyBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace from logcat?

Comment: Thank you for response . I just changed my intent code from           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); to intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK); and surprisingly it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, It seems ridiculous, just writing answer and hope will help someone. It is really wierd how it affects whole code.
When calling intent I used

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
```

Instead of

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

Comment: it's not working in OS: Android 5.1.1 and Device: OPPO A37f. How to solve this issue in specific android version

Comment: Actually, I haven't tested my code on various devices, so can't tell what could be a better solution. However, I would recommend using third party image picker libraries. Since they're implemented on different devices and are more reliable than android's Intent picker))